# Функция возвращает результат до отработки completionHandler`а другой функции, как исправить?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

столкнулся с такой проблемой, и не могу понять, какие есть пути решения данной проблемы.

Для начала предположим, что у меня есть следующая функция

```
func summ(x: Int, y: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let result: Int = x + y
    completionHandler(result)
}
```

Далее мы хотим в другой функции как то обработать результат функции, указанной выше, и вернуть обработанное значение.

```
func summ(x: Int, y: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let result: Int = x + y
    completionHandler(result)
}


func getResult(x: Int, y: Int) -> (String) {
    let resultString: String = ""

    summ(x, y) { result in
        resultString = "Результат: \(String(result))" 
    }

    return resultString
}
```

Но при вызове `let resultString = getResult(x = 15, y = 10)` я получаю просто пустую строку.
При попытках найти ошибку, понял, что в данный метод создает `let resultString: String = ""` а после чего сразу возвращает эту переменную `return resultString`, и только После этого начинает работу `completionHandler`

Я бы хотел, чтобы мой return возвращал значение ПОСЛЕ того, как полностью отработает completionHandler, а не до этого.

Замечание: Я предположу, что скорее всего будет предложено прям в комплишн хэндлере и обновить значение, присвоив ему правильное, но данное решение мне не подходит. В данном случае функции были взяты из головы, для упрощения понимания, в реальности, я с помощью CoreLocation получаю координаты по названию города, а после чего, в другой функции, мне нужно вернуть значение погоды по координатам, которые я получаю, как назло, в комплишн хэндлере...

Т.к. я только начал учить язык, возможно, я как то не так объяснил свою проблему, но надеюсь на понимание.

Про возможное решение, которое мне не совсем подходит:

```
let resultString: String = ""

func summ(x: Int, y: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let result: Int = x + y
    completionHandler(result)
}


func getResult(x: Int, y: Int) {
    summ(x, y) { result in
        resultString = "Результат: \(String(result))"
        self.resultString = resultString
    }
}
```

Comment: Второй вариант функции у вас правильный, вам нужно еще добавить в нее необходимые обновления UI или погоды и weak вместо self во избежание утечки памяти. А лучше вынесите все обновления в отдельную функцию и вызовите ее из закрытия. Получится цепочка вызовов функция 1 -> закрытие -> функция 2.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, второй вариант я бы не назвал "правильным". Он рабочий, да. Но с одним изьяном -- не понятно когда уже можно читать значение `resultString`. Повесить цикл и проверять ее на `isNotEmpty`? Не уверен что это лучшее решение.

Comment: В своем UPD вы как раз написали моё предложение, непонятно, о чём спор)

Answer (score 0):

Если отбросить новые фичи языка, то наверное это может выглядеть так:

```
func getResult(x: Int, y: Int) -> (String) {
    var resultString: String = ""

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    summ(x: x, y: y) { result in
        resultString = "Результат: \(String(result))" 
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()

    return resultString
}
```

Получается блокирующая функция, которую нельзя вызывать из `.main`

**UPD:** Все-таки для начинающего `DispatchGroup` слишком сложно, можно обойтись классическим решением попроще (никаких глобальных переменных и ожиданий значений из асинхронных функций):

```
func summ(x: Int, y: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let result: Int = x + y
    completionHandler(result)
}

func getResult(x: Int, y: Int) {
    summ(x, y) { result in
        updateResult("Результат: \(String(result))")
    }
}

func updateResult(strResult: String) {
    // здесь делайте все что вам нужно с новым значением
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, функция застревает на `dispatchGroup.wait()` и просто перестает все работать(

Comment: `wait()` блокирует поток в котором вызывается, поэтому нельзя использовать `.main`, и `summ` должна вызывать `completionHandler` из другого потока (быть асинхронной). Вот тут много чего об этом всем написано: https://betterprogramming.pub/a-deep-dive-into-dispatch-groups-8251bbb8b001

Comment: Хм, а мне казалось это первое что спрашивают на собеседованиях, поэтому стараюсь как раз таки учить и закреплять знания по GCD, как и по Unit-тестам, и работе по архитектурам. В целом, мне просто было интересно разобраться, как можно манипулировать обработчиками завершения. К сожалению, некоторые стандартные методы swift присылают данные именно в него, что не всегда удобно, как по мне, мне больше по душе func x() -> Any {}, нежели чем в хэндлер, но ничего не поделать, я уж смирился, что если уж начались клоужеры, то так в них и работать (клоужер в клоужере и так далее)

Comment: Вообще уже есть `async/await`, так что колбэки потихоньку уйдут в прошлое :) https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/async-await/